# Getting Total seconds from DateTime php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to convert the DateTime after I did a dateDiff to the queried time and the current time into seconds.  How do i do that?  I currently have it as hh:mm:ss.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$statusTime = $row['date'];

$dteStart = new DateTime($statusTime);
$dteEnd = new DateTime($currentTime);
$dteDiff = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
echo $dteDiff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Strtotime` will give you the time in seconds from 1 of january 1970.

So:

```
$statustimeUNIX = Strtotime(date("hh:mm:ss",$statusTime));
$currenttimeUNIX = Strtotime(date("hh:mm:ss", $currentTime));

$DiffInSeconds = $currenttimeUNIX - $statustimeUNIX; // or if it's supposed to be the other way around maybe?
```

There is no need for datetime here unless you need it for something else?

EDIT:

```
$statustimeUNIX = Strtotime(date("hh:mm:ss",$statusTime));
$currenttimeUNIX = Strtotime(date("hh:mm:ss", $currentTime));

$DiffInSeconds = $currenttimeUNIX - $statustimeUNIX;
If($DiffInSeconds > 300 || ($DiffInSeconds > -86100 && $DiffInSeconds < 0)){
   Echo "inactive";
}else{
   Echo "active";
}
```

Comment: @Alan, question: do you only have hhmmss timestamp or is that what you want to work with? Because lets say the querytime is 23:59:59, and currenttime is 00:00:01 then you will get a negative value, right? If you can, use "Y-m-d" also. Or you have to look at the timevalue and add "Ymd" depending on what the time is so that you don't get negative values.

Comment: I am working with mysql timestamp format.  I am trying to create sort of a heartbeat detection.  My raspberry pi is writing to my mysql database constantly and the date column updates every time the raspberry pi writes to it.  So I want to detect if the difference current time and query time is greater than 5 minutes then it will echo that it is offline

Comment: @Alan in that case you really need the date or a fake date. As you said if it's higher than 300 seconds, but what if it's `-86300` seconds? That is ~1,5 min difference across midnight.

Comment: @Alan I edited my answer to take care of negative value without a date. I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: @Alan so? Does it work? If yes, please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use `strtotime()` function which returns a unix timestamp.

`strtotime($dteDiff->format());` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get seconds between two DateTime objects is to do a simple subtraction:-

```
$dteStart = new DateTime($statusTime);
$dteEnd = new DateTime($currentTime);
$seconds = $dteEnd->getTimestamp() - $dteStart->getTimestamp();
```